# explaining the behavior of this "static variable" in C

Tags: c, debugging, static-variables

I'm reading "hacking, The Art of Exploitation" book, and this code sample really confuses me.

It's within the context of Global Variable Scope:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function() { // An example function, with its own context
    int var = 5;
    static int static_var = 5; // Static variable initialization
    printf("\t[in function] var = %d\n", var);
    printf("\t[in function] static_var = %d\n", static_var);
    var++; // Add one to var.
    static_var++; // Add one to static_var.
}

int main() { // The main function, with its own context
    int i;
    static int static_var = 1337; // Another static, in a different context
    for(i=0; i < 5; i++) { // Loop 5 times.
        printf("[in main] static_var = %d\n", static_var);
        function(); // Call the function.
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ gcc static.c
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $ ./a.out
[in main] static_var = 1337
    [in function] var = 5
    [in function] static_var = 5
[in main] static_var = 1337
    [in function] var = 5
    [in function] static_var = 6
[in main] static_var = 1337
    [in function] var = 5
    [in function] static_var = 7
[in main] static_var = 1337
    [in function] var = 5
    [in function] static_var = 8
[in main] static_var = 1337
    [in function] var = 5
    [in function] static_var = 9
reader@hacking:~/booksrc $
```

The question is that, WHY `[in function] var = 5` remains steady? We defined `var++;` as well as `static_var++;` within the local function. What is happening?

Comment: Because that's how non-static local variables work?

Comment: What behavior do you expect to differ between `static` and non-`static` variable?

Comment: Why is the title of this question "weird behavior of a **static variable**" when you are *very clearly* asking about a non-static (local) variable?

Comment: PS, I have to ask: This is chapter 1 (or 0) of N in a book about exploitation. What is N?

Comment: Thanks for your comments .. I changed the title of my question ...

Comment: @Soask Sorry, but you don't get it. You're asking " WHY [in function] var = 5 remains steady". `var` is not static. Therefore this question has **nothing** to do with static variables. You could delete everything to do with the static variables in your code and see the same behavior!

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks .. Regarding to your second question, this book has 8 chapters. Programming (our topic) is the second chapter ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is precisely what distinguishes a static variable from a non-static one. A static variable has static-storage-duration, meaning the variable *stays alive* during the run of the program. Non-static variables have automatic storage duration; meaning it will disappear at the end of the scope in which it was created (in this case, at the end of `function`). When the variable is disposed of, the next time the function is invoked, a new instance of that variable will be created.

Answer (score 5):

After the

```
var++;
```

in `function()`, that local variable is not used anymore. It goes out of scope and ceases to exist when the function returns. When `function()` is invoked the next time, a new `var` is allocated and initialised to `5`.

The two `static_var`s have static storage duration, they exist throughout the lifetime of the programme. Any modification to these persists and they are only initialised once.

So when `function()` is invoked the next time, the increment done in the previous invocation is still in effect, the initialisation is not executed except in the very first invocation.

Answer (score 3):

Because `var` is not static.  It's a different instance each time the function gets called.